# How to return single string value of XPath expression?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

This is my HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<div class="single-main"> 
  <h3 class="description-area">Description</h3>  
  <p>bla bla bla
    <br/> some text 
    <br/> some text here ,
    <br/> other text here
  </p> 
</div>
```

I want to get the whole text but in **one** XPath expression.

This is my code:

```
response.xpath(".//h3[@class='description-area']/following-sibling::p
                //text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) >= 0]").extract()[0]
```

but it returns just the text before the first `br` (I know why, and that's because I am using `.extract()[0]` and if i used .extract()[1] and [2] .... I will get what I want, but I **must** use .extract[0] because it is a platform that does just that.   Is there any XPath to return the whole text but in one string rather than in multiple strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string(/)` will return the string value of the whole document.

---

**Update**: To return the four separate strings returned by this XPath,

```
.//h3[@class='description-area']/following-sibling::p//text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) >= 0]
```

as a single string, wrap the above XPath similarly in `string()`:

```
string(.//h3[@class='description-area']/following-sibling::p//text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) >= 0])
```

---

**Update 2**: But the `br` and `text()` maneuvers aren't necessary.  You can simply get the string value of the `p`:

```
string(.//h3[@class='description-area']/following-sibling::p)
```

Comment: do you imply to use this please `.//h3[@class='description-area']/following-sibling::p//string()`